# Facing issue when doing SSR with caching in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, server-side-rendering

How to do SSR caching with NEXTJS.
I have used cache control settings in next.config.js file, but it work while redirection, directly opening the file is not working.

> Www.xyz.com/doc1 -> opening directly will not be cached

> Www.xyz.com -> going here and then redirecting to doc1 will be able to cache

**What is the best possible way to cache the SSR pages with cache control or  other way ?**